# how can i get the sum of the comboboxes using switch case?

Tags: java, swing, combobox, sum

```
public class Try1 extends JFrame{

private final String [] a1 = {"","Angus Burger - P60", "Australasian Burger - P60", "BBQ Burger - P60", "Buffalo Burger - P60"};
private final String [] a2 = {"","Spaghetti - P120", "Lasagna - P120", "Carbonara - P120", "Fettuccine - P120"};
private final String [] a3 = {"","Hawaiian - P300", "Bacon & Mushroom- P300", "Cheese Overload- P300", "Vegan's Pizza- P300"};
private final String [] a4 = {"","Dry Yogurt- P100" , "Ice cream- P100", "Pie- P100", "Cheese Cake- P100"};
private final String [] a5 = {"","Soda - P50", "Juice - P50", "Fruit Punch - P50", "Smoothie - P50"};
private JComboBox x1,x2,x3,x4,x5;
private JTextField price1,price2,price3;


public Try1(){

    super("Kevin's Fast Food Delivery");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, "Please, input your order");
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,2));

    JLabel z1 = new JLabel("Burgers");
    x1 = new JComboBox(a1);
    JLabel z2 = new JLabel("Pasta");
    x2 = new JComboBox(a2);
    JLabel z3 = new JLabel("Pizza");
    x3 = new JComboBox(a3);
    JLabel z4 = new JLabel("Desserts");
    x4 = new JComboBox(a4);
    JLabel z5 = new JLabel("Drinks");
    x5 = new JComboBox(a5);

    JLabel c1 = new JLabel("Total Ordered:");
    price1 = new JTextField("0",15);
    price1.setBounds(150,150,50,20);
    price1.setEditable(false);

    JLabel c2 = new JLabel("Money on Hand:");
    price2 = new JTextField("0",15);

    JLabel c3 = new JLabel("Total:");
    price3 = new JTextField("0",15);
    price3.setBounds(150,150,50,20);
    price3.setEditable(false);


    panel.add(z1);
    panel.add(x1);
    panel.add(z2);
    panel.add(x2);
    panel.add(z3);
    panel.add(x3);
    panel.add(z4);
    panel.add(x4);
    panel.add(z5);
    panel.add(x5);



    panel.add(c1);
    panel.add(price1);
    panel.add(c2);
    panel.add(price2);
    panel.add(c3);
    panel.add(price3);
    add(panel);

    ItemListener jcb = new ItemHandler();
    x1.addItemListener(jcb);
    x2.addItemListener(jcb);
    x3.addItemListener(jcb);
    x4.addItemListener(jcb);
    x5.addItemListener(jcb);


}





private class ItemHandler implements ItemListener{


    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent y) {

        double value = Double.parseDouble(price1.getText());
        double r = 0;






        Object source = y.getItemSelectable();

        if(source== x1){
            int a = x1.getSelectedIndex();
                       switch(a){
                           case 0: r = 0;
                           break;

                           case 1: r = 60;
                           break;

                           case 2: r = 60;
                           break;

                           case 3: r = 60;
                           break;

                           case 4: r = 60;
                           break;
                    }
        }

            if(source== x2){
                int b = x2.getSelectedIndex();
                        switch(b){
                           case 0: r = 0;
                           break;

                           case 1: r = 120;
                           break;

                           case 2: r = 120;
                           break;

                           case 3: r = 120;
                           break;

                           case 4: r = 120;
                           break;


                   }
            }                

            if(source== x3){
                int c = x3.getSelectedIndex();
                     switch(c){
                           case 0: r = 0;
                           break;

                           case 1: r = 300;
                           break;

                           case 2: r = 300;
                           break;

                           case 3: r = 300;
                           break;

                           case 4: r = 300;
                           break;


                   }
            }

            if(source== x4){
                int d = x4.getSelectedIndex();
                   switch(d){
                           case 0: r = 0;
                           break;

                           case 1: r = 100;
                           break;

                           case 2: r = 100;
                           break;

                           case 3: r = 100;
                           break;

                           case 4: r = 100;
                           break;




                    }

            }

            if(source== x5){
                int e = x5.getSelectedIndex();

                   switch(e){
                           case 0: r = 0;
                           break;

                           case 1: r = 50;
                           break;

                           case 2: r = 50;
                           break;

                           case 3: r = 50;
                           break;

                           case 4: r = 50;
                           break;


                }

            }




           price1.getDouble = r+r
    }
}





    public void createAndShowGUI(){
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(500,500);
    setLocation(100,100);
    }


    public static  void  main(String args[]){
    Try1 ty = new Try1();
    ty.createAndShowGUI();
    ty.pack();


}

}
```

i need to get the sum of the selected comboboxboxes but idk which is the proper method to use and idk if my switch case statements are right. anyone, please help. i would really appreciate for those who will help.

Comment: Your variable names are terrible

Comment: can you help me? like for only getting the sum of the desired comboboxes and putting it in the textfield of price1

Comment: I would re-do the whole thing. I'd create a FoodItem class that held the item name, type and per-item cost, and would use JComboBoxes of objects of this class.

Comment: Wrap each item in you comboboxes in a POJO which has a "display" value and a "numeric" value associated with it.  Then place all your combo boxes within an array, loop over them, getting the selected item from each and using it's "numeric" value to calculate the sum

Comment: Agree with @HovercraftFullOfEels. In addition to it, I would use collections of components (for example `List<JComboBox>`) instead of multiplying the number of variables.

Comment: can you pls elaborate? im only a first year college. or do src if can.

Comment: guys can you do some src samples for me? im really confused

Answer (score 0):

First of all: use 'combobox.getSelectedItem()' and leave those switchstatements out. Either use a map, if the prices differ from item to item, or use an if-statement, if the prices are all the same (`combobox.getSelectedItem()` will return null, if no item is selected). Use `price1.setText(newPrice)` to update the value in the ui. The simplest way would probably be a map with all items mapped to their prices and using this in itemStateChanged:

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e){
     if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED){
          double price = priceMap.get(e.getItem());

          //do something with the price
     }
 }
```

would look somehow like this in the end:

```
 ...
 public Try1(){
     HashMap<String , Double> prices = new HashMap<>();
     prices.put("" , 0.0);
     prices.put("Angusburger - P60" , 60.0);
     //put all the other items into the map

     ...
     ItemListener jcb = new ItemHandler(prices);
     ...
 }

 private class ItemHandler implements ItemListener{
      private HashMap<String , Double> prices;

      public ItemHandler(HashMap<String , Double> prices){
           this.prices = prices;
      }

      public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e){
           if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED){
                 double total = 0.0;

                 total += prices.get(x1.getSelectedItem());
                 total += prices.get(x2.getSelectedItem());
                 total += prices.get(x3.getSelectedItem());
                 total += prices.get(x4.getSelectedItem());
                 total += prices.get(x5.getSelectedItem());

                 price1.setText("" + total);
           }
      }                     
 }
```

Comment: so ill delete all switch cases and replace them with that?

Comment: would be much simpler and alterable. and you'll have to create a map with all the prices (put null , 0 aswell for no selected item).

Comment: paul, thanks for your time but can you use my code and alter it? @.@ im really bad at programming

Comment: @kevin so you should become a better programmer... you won't be able to always ask to the others to do your own job

Comment: actually, im taking up Electronics and Communication Engr and maths are my major. So im having a really hard time tackling this Sir. Dici

Answer (score 0):

As you seem to need a few more pointers, here is the idea first proposed by **Hovercraft Full Of Eels** :

first define a `FoodItem` class

```
public class FoodItem {
    private String name;
    private double cost;

    public FoodItem(String name, double cost) {
        this.name = name;
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    @Override 
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    public getCost() {
        return cost;
    }
}
```

Then, use `JComboBox<FoodItem>`. My personal addition to **Hovercraft Full Of Eels's** proposition is to use a list to store the boxes :

```
List<JComboBox<FoodItem>> boxes = Arrays.asList(
    new JComboBox<>(new FoodItem[] { new FoodItem("...",...),new FoodItem("...",...),new FoodItem("...",...) }),
    new JComboBox<>(new FoodItem[] { new FoodItem("...",...),new FoodItem("...",...),new FoodItem("...",...) }),
    new JComboBox<>(new FoodItem[] { new FoodItem("...",...),new FoodItem("...",...),new FoodItem("...",...) }),
    new JComboBox<>(new FoodItem[] { new FoodItem("...",...),new FoodItem("...",...),new FoodItem("...",...) })
    new JComboBox<>(new FoodItem[] { new FoodItem("...",...),new FoodItem("...",...),new FoodItem("...",...) }));

// compute the total
double total = 0;
for (JComboBox<FoodItem> box : boxes) total += box.getSelectedItem().getCost();
```

Answer (score 0):

## First...

Create a POJO which encapsulates the data you need, including the text to be displayed and the value of the item...

```
public interface FoodItem {
    public String getText();
    public double getCost();
}
```

## Second...

Create an array or `List` of the comboboxes

```
private List<JComboBox> foodItems;
//...
foodItems = new ArrayList<JComboBox>(5);
foodItems.add(createFoodItemComboBox(
    createFoodItem("Angus Burger", 60), 
    createFoodItem("Australasian Burger", 60),
    createFoodItem("BBQ Burger", 60),
    createFoodItem("Buffalo Burger", 60));
//...

protected JComboBox<FoodItem> createFoodItemComboBox(FoodItem foodItems) {
    DefaultComboBoxModel<FoodItem> model = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>();
    for (FoodItem fi : foodItems) {
        model.addElement(fi);
    }
    JComboBox cb = new JComboBox<FoodItem>(model);
    return cb;
}

protected FoodItem createFoodItem(String text, double price) {
    // You'll have to create your own implementation of FoodItem
    return new DefaultFoodItem(text, price);
}
```

## Third...

Create a `ListCellRenderer` which can render the items the way you want...

```
public static class FoodItemListCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
        if (value instanceof FoodItem) {
            FoodItem fi = (FoodItem) value;
            setText(fi.getText() + " - " + NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(fi.getCost()));
        }
        return this;
    }

}
```

## Fourth...

Use an `ActionListener` to detect when the changes occur (I'd update the `createFoodItemComboBox` method to do this automatically)

```
private ActionListener actionHanlder = new ActionHandler();
//...
protected JComboBox<FoodItem> createFoodItemComboBox(FoodItem foodItems) {
    //...
    cb.addActionListener(actionHandler);
    return cb;
}

//...

public class ActionHandler implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        double tally = 0;
        for (JComboBox<FoodItem> cb : foodItems) {
            FoodItem fi = (FoodItem)cb.getSelectedItem();
            if (fi != null) {
                tally += fi.getCost();
            }
        }
        price1.setText(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(tally));
    }
}
```

For example

Comment: Sir, can you post a screencap of the program? idk what "foodItems = new ArrayList<JComboBox>(5);" means

Comment: and is this applicable in GUI form?

Comment: Yes, do this kind of thing all time